# Flexbox positioning IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

In spite of all my research, I can not fix the position of my grid with flexbox on IE11. There is no problem on other browsers, including Edge.

I have read the specifications of Flexbox on caniuse, but I still do not see how to solve my problem without breaking the setup on other browsers.

An idea ? Thank you very much.

#### [Codepen here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJaWvQ)

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.steps {
  .steps-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .step {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 25%;

    @media (max-width: 740px) {
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      width: 48%;
    }
  }

  .step__thumb {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 110px;
    line-height: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    width: 110px;
  }

  .step__text {
    color: lighten(#202124, 20%);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    list-style: circle;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="band steps">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="steps-list">
          <div class="step">
            <div class="step__thumb"></div>
            <div class="step__text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias similique quidem ab ratione expedita, repellat laborum praesentium, pariatur a nulla ipsa alias corrupti eum illum fugiat saepe quos unde iste.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="step">
            <div class="step__thumb"></div>
            <div class="step__text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias similique quidem ab ratione expedita, repellat laborum praesentium, pariatur a nulla ipsa alias corrupti eum illum fugiat saepe quos unde iste.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="step">
            <div class="step__thumb"></div>
            <div class="step__text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias similique quidem ab ratione expedita, repellat laborum praesentium, pariatur a nulla ipsa alias corrupti eum illum fugiat saepe quos unde iste.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="step">
            <div class="step__thumb"></div>
            <div class="step__text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias similique quidem ab ratione expedita, repellat laborum praesentium, pariatur a nulla ipsa alias corrupti eum illum fugiat saepe quos unde iste.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: You can try to look at ie11 and known issues http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Add `width: 100%` to `.step__text`

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/WpgjMX)

I'm not entirely sure why this works, but I had a similar issue before, and defining a width seemed to work.

Comment: Finally so simple... thanks !